# hexo d and hexo deploy -g are not working

Tags: hexo

I am trying to push my hexo blog to my github repository, untill the last step, hexo d is not working, I have also tried with hexo deploy -g, also not working. So my repository is not updating.

I could not find .deploy folder in my blog root folder. It's said to delete this folder could also be a solution.

I am not sure what's wrong with this.

```
hexo d      - with no output at all
-----------
hexo deploy -g    - the output is listed below, so i guess the hexo g works.
-----------
hexo clean
hexo g
hexo d

none is working
```

_config.yml

```
deploy:
  type:git
  repo:https://github.com/puddlejumper26/xiangblog.github.io.git
```

with hexo d

```
d:\100-Blog\xiang>hexo d

d:\100-Blog\xiang>
```

with hexo deploy g

```
d:\100-Blog\xiang>hexo deploy g
INFO  Start processing
INFO  Files loaded in 725 ms
INFO  Generated: index.html
INFO  Generated: archives/index.html
INFO  Generated: fancybox/blank.gif
INFO  Generated: fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css
INFO  Generated: fancybox/fancybox_loading.gif
INFO  Generated: fancybox/fancybox_loading@2x.gif
INFO  Generated: fancybox/fancybox_overlay.png
INFO  Generated: fancybox/fancybox_sprite@2x.png
INFO  Generated: archives/2019/01/index.html
INFO  Generated: fancybox/fancybox_sprite.png
INFO  Generated: archives/2019/index.html
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/FontAwesome.otf
INFO  Generated: js/script.js
INFO  Generated: fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css
INFO  Generated: fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
INFO  Generated: fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js
INFO  Generated: css/style.css
INFO  Generated: fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js
INFO  Generated: fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
INFO  Generated: fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js
INFO  Generated: fancybox/helpers/fancybox_buttons.png
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
INFO  Generated: 2019/01/16/hello-world/index.html
INFO  Generated: css/images/banner.jpg
INFO  Generated: fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js
INFO  28 files generated in 1.96 s
```

Answer (score 1):

i got it fixed, it's in the _config.yml file,

after :, there should be a space, otherwise, the file could not be used

**wrong version:**

```
deploy:
  type:git
  repo:https://github.com/puddlejumper26/xiangblog.github.io.git
```

**right version:**

```
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: https://github.com/puddlejumper26/xiangblog.github.io.git
```